# My .apk is 273MB because of my images for animation, isn't that too much?

Tags: android

I never saw an app that is 273MB, I have to be doing something wrong; I have 75 pngs for an animation. An app is not supposed to be that big, right?

Comment: 75 pngs account for a significant part of 273 mb ? don't you have memory issues with that ?

Comment: i never even ran it, i just built it and looked at the apk, is there a better way to animate?

Comment: probably. run it, to begin with. i doubt it will even load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can definitely be that size. Many games are huge in size. You'll have to use the APK expansion files method provided by google for this. See here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

You'll have to store them on the SD card as they'll be too big for internal memory.

Also consider compression or smaller file sizes as alternatives although this depends highly on what you plan to do with your images (if it's very important that the images be high-res, then don't compress).

Comment: is there some examples of how to go about doing this, seperate drawable folders from build of apk and all?

Comment: I haven't found any tutorials as such but the developer docs link I gave has quite a detailed checklist of what you need to go. You could go through it thoroughly and try once.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Google Play website](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469) the maximum allowed size for the APK on Google Play is 50 MB but you can use [expansion files mechanism](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2481797) if you need more data (2GB per file)

I'd suggest you though to find a way to use fewer PNG images or optimize it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

You can put your images on a server and first time entering your app download them on the sdcard. You'll know better if this fits your application :)